# What is BDB for in Python?

Tags: python, debugging

I was looking through the Python standards libs and saw BDB the debugger framework. What is it for and can I get additional value from it?
At the moment I use Eclipse/PyDev with the internal debugger which also supports conditionals breakpoints. Can I get something new from BDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `bdb` module implements the basic debugger facilities for `pdb.Pdb`, which is the concrete debugger class that is used to debug Python scripts from a terminal.

Unless you're planning to write your own debugger user interface, you shouldn't need to use anything from `bdb`.